# Controlling the scope of \label and \ref

Tags: cross-referencing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I re-use section labels across chapters?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82091/can-i-re-use-section-labels-across-chapters)

Is there a way to control the scope of the command `\label` and `\ref`?

In document `chap1.tex`, I declare the label `\label{lemma}` and access it with `\ref{lemma}`.
In document `chap2.tex`, I also declare the label `\label{lemma}` and access it with `\ref{lemma}`.

Then, in `book.tex`, the error `multiply defined label` is raised.

I understand the error wouldn't be raised if I use `\label{1:lemma}` and `\label{2:lemma}`.

Is it possible to redefined the command `label` and `ref` so that
`\label{lemma}` produces the key `chap1:lemma`, and
`\ref{lemma}` invokes the key `chap1:lemma`.
That is `label` and `ref` based themselves on the current document name.

Any other solution is also welcome.

Comment: have you seen [Can I re-use section labels across chapters?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/82091)

Comment: And what will you do if you have to reference in chapter 2 a lemma of chapter 1? The best way is to use for each label a significant name, for example `lem:def-R` for the definition of real numbers R. A good editor can show you all til now used labels to choose the right one for referencing ...

Comment: And what if you have two `lemma`s in the same chapter?

Comment: Related/duplicate: [How to create *local* labels/refs in LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/73112). For example: `\newcommand*\labellocal[1]{\label{\thechapter:#1}}
\newcommand*\reflocal[1]{\ref{exer:\thechapter:#1}}`

Comment: The [`xr` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/xr) helps you out in terms of `\label`. You'll have to do something similar for `\ref`. With an automated process and regular `\label`-`\ref`s, you would most likely not be able to reference across chapters.

Comment: If you say "document `chap1.tex`", maybe every chapter is a separate article? In this case you could combine them using the `combine` package. It will also take care of labels.